# Zend Framework 2 use Session to login user

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2, zend-session

I'm starting on Zend Framework 2, I did the tutorial on album, nos I want to connect users, the sign up is working, so now I diplayed a form, and now I don't know how to use sessions:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.config.html

How I show theform connection:

connection.phtml:

```
<?php

  $title = 'Connection';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<p class="descr">Veuillez remplir entièrement ce formulaire et le valider pour vous inscrire.</p>
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('inscription', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
// echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('pseudo'));
echo "<br/>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('mdp'));
echo "<br/>";
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Controller:

```
   public function connectionAction() {
//        return new ViewModel(array(
//            'users' => $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll(),
//        ));


         $form = new ConnectionForm();
         $form->get('submit')->setValue('Se connecter');

         $request = $this->getRequest();
         if ($request->isPost()) {
             $form->setData($request->getPost());

             if ($form->isValid()) {
                 $user->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                 $this->getUserTable()->saveUser($user);

                 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
             }
         }
         return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

Comment: From what I can see, your code is only for sign up. ZF2 has Authentication component (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html) that you can use for logging in.

Comment: @Adam my code is just to display the form to sign up, I'm gonna look at this component, but it look with less exemples. What do you think about using session ?